# why does gmail (and google spreadsheet) display dates in xlsx file as integers by default

Tags: excel, google-sheets, gmail, google-sheets-api

When I preview an xlsx file in gmail the cells of dates display as integers. For example the date (formatted as dd/mm/yyyy) 20/06/2018 is displayed 43271. The same holds when opening the file by Google Spreadsheet (GS) because the date cells are identified as number formatted. 
Tried to change Gmail language settings but with no effect.
**My question:** Is there a fix to enable a correct date format in gmail preview without having to download the file and open it with Excel or Calc?
An answer that further explains why GS is behaving so will be more appreciated (I am not seeking an answer that explains the integer is the number of days starting from a given date but technically explains why GS fails to display the suitable date).

Comment: Because if google gives you 43259 instead of 06/08/2018, it doesn't have to decide if that is 08-Jun-2018 or 06-Aug-2018. DMY vs MDY is left up to you, not google.

Comment: @Jeeped, it can decide if it is DMY or MDY according to language settings.

Comment: But it doesn't have to if it leaves it up to you.

Comment: @Jeeped, do you think that it is a deliberate choice?

Comment: Yes, IMHO I do but you could ask them for a more definitive response.

Comment: Google is giving you the days since new years 1900. This as per above is so that it doesn't have to guess/assume your localization requirements for the date display format

Comment: @I'-'I, "The same holds when opening the file by Google Spreadsheet (GS)".

Comment: @I'-'I, yes of course but it isn't what I am asking for.